# Cant install wine on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, wine

I try to install wine as the website suggested but something is wrong..

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds



   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1243, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1252, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 102, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1286, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1245, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 327, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 108, in _get_https_content_py3
    raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 393, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 356, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 339, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
softwareproperties.shortcuts.ShortcutException: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~wine/ubuntu/wine-builds'.
The team named '~wine' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/wine-builds'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'test-builds':  test-builds
 * 'wine-builds':  Official Wine builds
Error: 'ppa:wine/wine-builds' invalid
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Just use `sudo apt-get install wine`

Answer (score 0):

As Inforcer25 said in the comments, you don't need to add the PPA.

Unless you want the newest betas, there is no point.

So, fire up your terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```